# PosPrinter.PrintNormal for hebrew language

Tags: c#, printing, hebrew

I got IBM 4160  Printer TF6
when i try to print things in hebrew it prints me unrecognizes tokens
the thing is how i force the printer for hebrew character set? is it possible
i use C# with it 
Microsoft Pos.Net and as i saw for english it works perfect but hebrew as problem

```
printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"Hebrew text");
```

Here is what i found when i try to print hebrew in DOS (echo "text in hebrew">com1)
it works fine and the printer prints in hebrew..

so the problem is with my programed code 
if someone could help ill appreciate it

Comment: This is surely CharacterSet trouble.  Looks like the printer is setup for DOS codepage 862 but your program is liable to use Windows codepage 1255.  Something like that.  Ought to be mentioned in the printer manual.

Comment: I thought that as well, how do i fix it? did u have any idea?